# Grep Regex match not returning result as expected

Tags: command-line, server, package-management, grep, regex

I have several Ubuntu servers and there is some behavior that has me curious.

On any newly installed machine (Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS), if I run:

```
echo "testbla123" | grep -P -o [0-9]*
```

This will return `123` as expected.

On an older machine (Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS), if I run the same command, I get nothing back, I have to instead run:

```
echo "testbla123" | grep -P -o "[0-9]*"
```

After performing an `apt-get upgrade`, it will perform without quotes around the regex.

Grep is at the same versions on both machines. I tried comparing dependencies before and after the update for some time without much luck.

I was wondering if anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 6):

Chances are you have a file that matches the glob pattern `[0-9]*` on your second machine, and not on the first one. If that's the case, the shell will expand the glob into the file's name before passing that as an argument to `grep`.

If there is no file that match on the current directory, the shell leaves the glob pattern untouched and passes it as-is to the command.

```
$ echo abc123 | grep -P -o [0-9]*
123
$ touch 234
$ echo abc123 | grep -P -o [0-9]* # shell runs grep -P -o 234
$ touch 123
$ echo abc123 | grep -P -o [0-9]* # shell runs grep -P -o 123 234
$ rm 234 123
$ touch 12
$ echo abc123 | grep -P -o [0-9]* # shell runs grep -P -o 12
12
$
```

Always quote parameters that contain shell wildcards if you don't want them to be expanded by the shell.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and will continue to do it in quotes, however, the moment that I perform an update on the older machines, it works... I really want an explanation on what update could have caused a syntax change when Grep itself remains the same version.

Comment: Are you 100% certain you ran those commands in the same directory before and after the upgrade? Was the shell upgraded?

Comment: The syntax of Grep has never changed. As Mat explained, the problem here is not grep, but it's the shell which is doing "too much". Instead of `echo something | grep expr`, try just `echo expr`. Or maybe try running `set -x` before typing any command.

Comment: @Mat - Yes I am

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini - I fully understand that, and as I said, it was the same Grep version on both machines, it suddenly started working after doing an update - I am certain it was something shell or dependency related, I am just not sure what and that is what I would like to know!

Comment: I guess a change in the PCRE library could have affected this (since `grep -P` uses that I believe), but that does sound really far-fetched @wilhil.